# taking random sample of text chunks python

Tags: python, random, types

I'm trying to take random samples of length k from each line in a string of text to create a list of text chunks, but I keep getting a `type error` even though I can print out a bunch of random numbers that appear in a list. the `int()` function doesn't help in this case. Am I thinking about this all wrong? Does the random package have a better implementation? I know this is a really quick fix, but I guess I just don't know enough about data types to implement the right solution:

```
text = '''blahblahblah
blahblahblah
blahblahblah'''



import random
def randomtext(Text,k):
    chunks = []
    textspl = text.split('\n')
    tlen = len(textspl[0])-k
    for i in range(len(text)):
        samp = random.sample(tlen,1)
        chunks.append(text[i][samp:samp+k])
    return chunks


randomtext(text,3)
TypeError: Population must be a sequence or set.  For dicts, use list(d)
```

Comment: Add the traceback with your error.

Comment: Can you explain how you expect this to work -- not the end result, but the steps to get there?  (I don't think it is a "really quick fix".)

Comment: `randomtext(Text,k):` - I assume it is just a typo in your variable name? `Text` as opposed to `text`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def randomtext(text,k):
    chunks = []
    for line in text.splitlines():
        position = random.randint(0, len(line)-k)
        chunks.append(line[position:position+k])
    return chunks
```